# PuTTY SSH Connection Closes Abruptly without Error

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty

I am encountering an issue while trying to connect to my server via SSH using PuTTY. I have successfully connected to the server using SSH from the command line, but when I attempt to use PuTTY, the application closes abruptly without providing any error messages. I've taken the following steps:

1. converted my PEM private key file to a PPK format using the command `puttygen key.pem -o key.ppk`.
2. opened PuTTY and provided the public IP address of my gateway server and set the port to 22.
3. In PuTTY, under SSH -> Auth, I loaded my private key file by selecting the "private key file for authentication" option and specifying the path to the key.ppk file.

When clicked on the open button the PuTTY application closes without displaying any error messages or warning.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on what might be causing this problem. How can I investigate and resolve this issue? Are there any logs or additional troubleshooting steps I should consider?

Comment: Have you tried turning on session logging and checked the log file for errors or messages? How about looking in /var/log/secure on the server? The name of that particular log may change depending on the syslog configuration.